# Reduce to map of type typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I have this configurations

```
type Option = {
  value: any,
  label: any
}
```

And

```
export interface Role {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

Then I have Roles

```
const roles:Role[]:[
{id:1,name:'name1'},
{id:2,name:'name2'},
{id:3,name:'name3'}
]
```

I want to extract **Option[]** from that roles dataset. How do i do it in javascript?

In **java** I could do

```
roles.stream().map(role->new Option(role.id,role.name)).collect(collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the roles to options:

```
type Option = {
  value: any;
  label: any;
}

interface Role {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const roles: Role[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'name1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'name2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'name3'}
];

const options: Option[] = roles.map(({id, name}) => ({value: id, label: name}));
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=83&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvAUFKAbgIYA2ArhAFxREogDceUJRARhCdbQzgL444EKYBABOAMyIBjaACUkJaLnwIAJtRRkAtu1GN8KIlqpQAzsFFCA5o344pqc1FEKIp6vMUBtALoYoXkxYatQAjAA0UIbG1ADk0RChsbzhQSFQAEyRCXEJGcmp+MHqUADM2UYm8ZWlyTg+jPaOwFBI8Mgo7rDtqL7+LoqmAHRaRGAAFOPFFca8AJQYAHxQU4SkFNRqkSzsnFGVUPNz9EA)

Answer (score 1):

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvAUFKAbgIYA2ArhAFxREogA0eUJRARhCdbSDgL444EKYBABOAMyIBjaACUkJaLnwIAJtRRkAtu1FMURLVSgBnYKKEBzPgKmozUUQognq8xQG0AuhigemWFBq1AAM9FAGRtQAROJISNFQvIz4gcFQAIzhkcbRrESiickBQepQAEzZhrn5AF5FjF629sCOLmQkwNRwiKjevk6KJkwAdFpEYAAUk2mqVUZJAJQYAHxQM8xsHNRq4cTkxjlLiwDczSgmziMkSJaTou2dp0A)

```js
type Option = {
  value: any,
  label: any
}

interface Role {
  id: number
  name: string
}

const roles: Role[] = [
  { id: 0, name: "foo" },
  { id: 1, name: "bar" },
  { id: 2, name: "baz" },
]

const result: Option[] = roles
  .map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: id, value: name }));

console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[LOG]: [{
  "label": 0,
  "value": "foo"
}, {
  "label": 1,
  "value": "bar"
}, {
  "label": 2,
  "value": "baz"
}]
```